# active classes for menu items , its should not active all list

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am trying to maintain active classes separate separate , but its active's all list , at same time , and it should toggle active classes for separate li's...can any one help on this..

this the link of code sand box  : https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-butterfly-4wjr7?file=/src/App.js:0-650

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './styles.css'
export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isactive: true
    };
  }
  clicked = e => {
    this.setState({
      isactive: !this.state.isactive
    });
  };
  render() {
    const lits = ["Menu 1", "Menu 1", "Menu 3", "Menu 4"];
    return (
      <div>
        {lits.map((list, key) => (
          <ul key={key}>
           <li className={this.state.isactive ? 'active' : 'notactive'}
           onClick={this.clicked}>
              {list}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

css

```
active {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: blue
}
.notactive {
  font-weight: 0;
}
```

Comment: where does `this.state.fontweight` come from?

Comment: sorry its "!this.state.isactive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an index for state and used that to toggle class -

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0
    };
  }
  clicked = index => {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
  };
  render() {
    const lits = ["Menu 1", "Menu 1", "Menu 3", "Menu 4"];
    return (
      <div>
        {lits.map((list, key) => (
          <ul key={key}>
            <li
              className={
                this.state.activeIndex === key ? "active" : "notactive"
              }
              onClick={this.clicked.bind(this, key)}
            >
              {list}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeKey: -1
    };
  }
  clicked = key => {
    this.setState({
      activeKey: key
    });
  };
  render() {
    const lits = ["Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3", "Menu 4"];
    return (
      <div>
        {lits.map((list, key) => (
          <ul key={key}>
            <li
              className={this.state.activeKey === key ? "active" : "notactive"}
              onClick={() => this.clicked(key)}
            >
              {list}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks fro your answer...when menu 1 selected its active , when i selected menu 2 , menu 1 should be not active and menu 2 should be active

Comment: @ManoharPamishetty I updated it. Can you check please ?